# Расположение Button и TextView в Activity

Tags: android, java, android-studio

Помогите новичку. Не могу разобраться: как расположить **Button** *в самом низу* LinearLayout, а **TextView** - *слева*?

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.05">
</Button>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
</TextView>
```

Comment: Что значит слева?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:textColor="#000" />
</FrameLayout>
```

А если нужно именно через линейный лейаут, то так:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textColor="#000" />
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:gravity="bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Используйте RelativeLayout. Он позволяет разместить компоненты относительно друг друга и относительно самого RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Этак можно получить наползание (перекрытие) одного элемента на другой.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а можнол и не получить. А можно получить и другим способом. Это зависит от того, откуда руки растут.

Comment: @metalurgus, не, оно понятно, конечно... Только вот, думаю, это - наиболее простой способ выстрелить себе в ногу в данной ситуации))

Answer (score 1):

Помимо **RelativeLayout**, коий "тяжелее" **LinearLayout**, можно вложить **Button** и **TextView** в другие **LinearLayout**, коим можно назначить свойство **Gravity**.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </Button>
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```